# = operator for a matrix class behaving weird

Tags: c++, class, operators, operator-keyword

CPP

```
#include "del2.h"

Matrix::Matrix()
{
    dArray = NULL;
}
bool Matrix::isValid() const
{
    if (dArray == NULL)
        return false;
    return true;
}
Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    delete [] dArray;
}
Matrix::Matrix(unsigned int nRows)
{
    rows = nRows;
    columns = nRows;
    dArray = new double[nRows * nRows];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int n = 0; n < nRows; n++)
        {
            at(i,n) = 0;
        }
    }
    at(0,0) = 1;
    at(rows-1,columns-1) = 1;
}
Matrix::Matrix(unsigned int nRows, unsigned int nColumns)
{
    dArray = new double[nRows * nColumns];
    rows = nRows;
    columns = nColumns;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
        for (unsigned int n = 0; n < nColumns; n++)
            dArray[i * columns + n] = 0;


}
const Matrix Matrix::operator =(const Matrix & rhs)
{
    columns = rhs.getColumns();
    rows = rhs.getRows();
    delete [] dArray;
    dArray = new double[rows * columns];
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
            at(row,column) = rhs.at(row,column);


    return *this;
}
std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream & out, const Matrix & classPrint )
{
    if (!classPrint.isValid())
        return out;
    int rows = classPrint.getRows();
    int columns = classPrint.getColumns();
    out << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
     {
        out << "| ";
        for (int n = 0; n < columns; n++)
            out << classPrint.at(i,n) << " ";
        out << "|" << std::endl;
    }
    out << endl;
    return out;
}
```

HEADER:

```
#ifndef DEL2
#define DEL2
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
private:
    int rows;
    int columns;
    double * dArray;
public:
    ~Matrix();
    Matrix();
    explicit Matrix(unsigned int nRows);
    Matrix(unsigned int nRows, unsigned int nColumns);
    const Matrix operator =(const Matrix & rhs);

    const double at(int row, int column) const
    { return dArray[ row*this->columns + column ]; }
    double & at( int row, int column )
    { return dArray[ row*this->columns + column ]; }

    const int getRows() const {return rows;}
    const int getColumns() const {return columns;}

    bool isValid() const;
};
std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream & out, const Matrix & classPrint );

#endif // MATRIX
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "del2.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Matrix A;
    Matrix B(10);
    A = B;
    cout << A;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, the following happens:

The first index, matrix[0] of A, always becomes some weird number like 2.22323e-306. I don't understand why. Even when I try to set "at(0,0) = 1;" in the operator = - function after the loop, it still doesn't have 0.

Comment: with floating point, I would not be surprised. That is essentially 0 for all intents and purposes. Does it cause any other error?

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of. It runs fine and everything, just the one value that's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
const Matrix operator =(const Matrix & rhs);
```

should be

```
const Matrix& operator =(const Matrix & rhs);
```

and the definition should be

```
const Matrix& Matrix::operator =(const Matrix & rhs)
{
   if (&rhs == this)
      return *this;
```

---

Otherwwise `operator=` is **returning a copy of the Matrix** which will have `dArray` same as the original Matrix. Your data will be `deleted` when the temporary returned array goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull the operator = is not correct

```
Matrix & operator = (const Matrix & rhs){
    if (&rhs != this){ 
     // Your stuff here
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Calling delete [] on a null array is undefined. It can crash.
You must also define the copy constructor